# task does not get 'failed' when using rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a task like this...

```
def self.perform(parsed_json)
 do_hard_work
 use_faye_to_push_status
 rescue => exception
   use_faye_to_push_error
end
```

but, when I use the 'rescue', the task doesn't enter on the failed task list. Is there a way to, even using `rescue`, set the task as failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rescuing from the error will stop it from proceeding any further up the call stack. With that said, you can simply `raise` again inside the `rescue` block in order to propagate it upwards:

```
def self.perform(parsed_json)
  do_hard_work
  use_faye_to_push_status
rescue => exception
  use_faye_to_push_error
  raise
end
```